# Android studio не видит телефон

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio не видит телефон. Этот же телефон на одном Студио отлично определяется, а на другом нет. Подключение через кабель usb. Режим debuggibg включен.

Comment: мало чего. Может, там драйвера не установлены (если это винда) или в правила udev не прописан (если это линукс). А может, просто телефон включил режим паранойи и не дает подключиться (а сам забыл спросить об этом, а может и спросил, но Вы сами забанили, актуально для андроидов начиная вроде с 4.3).

Comment: android studio версия 1.0 - не определяется девайся, причем на двух компах. На компе с андроид студия 0.8.6 - определяется. Телефон на компе определяется, но в андроид студио не появляется. Телефон с андроид 2.3 lg p970. Система на компе - Windows

Comment: подключайте телефон, а потом в менеджер устройств и смотрите, есть ли там Ваше устройство или там есть "неизвестные устройства". Если есть - доустанавливайте драйвера.

Comment: У разных телефонов бывают разные моды подключения, обычно это задается в настройках. Иногда бывает, что нужно устанавливать специальную моду. Например, в Самсунгах иногда работает только под модой камеры.

Answer (score 5):

Привет. Вот - попробуйте [adbinstaller](http://adbdriver.com/), он мне частенько помогает с недоустановленными драйверами, а также это может быть кабель (тот, что usb, но это только в случаях с samsung).

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваш комп видел телефон и перестал - дело в драйверах. Я пытался обновлять их и удалять - бесполезно, потом просто подключил к другому компу - о видит! Зашел в диспетчер устройств посмотрел какие и где лежат драйвера, а их там 6 файлов.
Скачал их на флешку, дома сбросил их на комп, выдернул флешку и просто заменил их перезаписью. Все работает, только с флешки не пытайтесь их заменить сразу - не получится, так как когда подключена флешка он использует драйвера и не даст их заменить.

Подробнее: скачиваем нижеприведённые файлы с компа, где телефон определяется, и меняем их там, где телефон не виден. *winusb.sys*, *WpdUpFltr.sys*, *WUDFRd.sys*, *WpdMtp.dll*, *WpdMtpDr.dll*, *WpdMtpUS.dll*.

Comment: Что-то сомнительный способ. И не помешало бы описать по-подробнее.

Comment: Поменьше восклицаний и сомнительных оборотов речи, пожалуйста, вы не в ВКонтакте общаетесь все же.